# Drop Down Menu on Sprite Navigation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, sprite

I need to put a drop down menu on a navigation that's based on one image (CSS Sprite). I've been trying for a few hours and I just can't figure it out. Here's the HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
                <li class="nav-1"><a href="/">Storage Auctions</a></li>
                <li class="nav-2"><a href="/blog.php">Blog</a></li>

                <li class="nav-3"><a href="/about.php">About</a>



                </li>

                <li class="nav-4"><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav-5"><a href="/faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
```

I need the drop down to go under the "About" link. I realize it had to go in the 'li' tag, but I can't get the CSS right. Here's the current CSS for this sprite:

```
ul#nav {
     margin:75px 0 0 0; 
     padding:0; 
     list-style:none;
     clear: both;    
}

 #nav li {
     overflow:hidden; 
     text-indent:-9999px; 
     display:inline; 
     float:left; 
     width: 398px;
}

#nav li a {
    background:url(../images/nav-sprite.jpg) no-repeat; 
    width: 398px; 
    height: 40px; 
    display:block;
}


 #nav li.nav-1 {width:85px; height:40px;}
 #nav li.nav-1 a:hover{background-position:0px -40px;}  

 #nav li.nav-2 {width:80px; height:40px;}  
 #nav li.nav-2 a:hover{background-position:-85px -40px;} 
 #nav li.nav-2 a{background-position:-85px 0px;} 

 #nav li.nav-3 {width:82px; height:40px;}  
 #nav li.nav-3 a:hover{background-position:-165px -40px;} 
 #nav li.nav-3 a{background-position:-165px 0px;} 

 #nav li.nav-4 {width:97px; height:40px;}  
 #nav li.nav-4 a:hover{background-position:-247px -40px;}
 #nav li.nav-4 a{background-position:-247px 0px;}  

 #nav li.nav-5 {width:54px; height:40px;}  
 #nav li.nav-5 a:hover{background-position:-344px -40px;} 
 #nav li.nav-5 a{background-position:-344px 0px;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Put all the styling on the `A`-tag, not the `LI`. (except for `float:left`)

Answer (score 0):

Give the #nav li a position: relative

Insert the ul in the li as you specify. Style #nav ul li ul to position: absolute. Give it a width and height and a top and left position in px. and a background color. (test that it shows before you set display none on it). Set it to display: none

Then on #nav li a:hover ul make it display: block

(I think this should work)

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this right now. I wish I would have done this in my initial post, but, here's a good working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kennyk3/TTDNp/

Comment: I tried your example and, unfortunately, it did not work. I've never had this much trouble figuring out CSS. I really just need a simple drop down menu with two items in it. If anyone can check that jsfiddle above and come up with a solution, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hi again. It was mostly because of your crazy styles it didn't work, text indent and such. I've created a new fiddle for you that has my changes and makes it work. Please note that li:hover that I added may not be compatible with all browsers, I'd perhaps use jquery as a backup. http://jsfiddle.net/mq8xX/

Comment: Hey, sorry, I haven't been back to check. I went ahead and scratched the sprite and just used text. It was much easier. Thanks for creating that example though, I'll know how to do one in the future now.